# HTML5 video onended event firing once

Tags: html, events, video

I am really stumped on this one.
I am trying to use the html5 video player and javascript in safari.  I want to 
1 play a greeting video
2 play a default looping video while the user makes a selection
3 play user selection
4 return to the default looping video.

1, 2, 3 work but 4 does not.

I call the greeting video from the body

```
<video id="videok" width=400 height=400 autoplay="autoplay" src="sacagreeting.mov" >

    video not supported
</video>
```

I set my event listener up in the body

```
body onload="myAddListener()"

 function myAddListener(){
    var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        myVideo.addEventListener('ended',myNewSrc,false);
        }
```

my function to play the looping default video is

```
function myNewSrc() {
        myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
        myVideo.src="sacarest.mov";
    myVideo.loop="loop";
        myVideo.load();
        myVideo.play();
    }
```

I use an select element for the user to pick a video and the onchange event to call my video function

```
function myNewSrcii() {

        myVideo = document.getElementById('videok');

    myVideo.loop=""

    myquest = document.getElementById('vidquest').value;

    switch(myquest)
    {
    case "a":
        myVideo.src="sacaa.mov"; 
        break;
    case "b":
        myVideo.src="sacab.mov";
        break;
    case "c":
        myVideo.src="sacac.mov";
        break;
    case "d":
        myVideo.src="sacad.mov";
        break;
    case "e":
        myVideo.src="sacae.mov";
        break;
    case "f":
        myVideo.src="sacaf.mov";

    }

     myVideo.load();
     myVideo.play();
}
```

I have tried dropping the looping attribute, setting the event listener again in the myNewSrcii function, using an onended event in the video tag and no luck.  When I check the video event ended is true, the listener however never calls my default video function.  Any help would be greatly apprectiated.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a strange bug in Safari's HTML5 video tag implementation. It can be reproduced on Safari for Windows as well. I've just found one workaround for this problem - just bind to `loadedmetadata` event and set the `currentTime` to some non-zero value. Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" width="500" height="400" controls autoplay></video>
<script>
var src = [
 "http://content.adfox.ru/131007/adfox/205544/865991_11.mp4",
 "http://all.rutube.ru/130627/gpmdigital/217059/805529_11.mp4"
];
var curSrc = 0;
$(function() {
 $('#video').attr("src", src[curSrc % src.length]);
 curSrc++;
 var video = $('#video').get(0);

 $('#video')
 .on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  video.currentTime=0.01;
  video.play();
 })
 .on('ended', function() {
  console.log('ended');
  video.src = src[curSrc % src.length];
  video.load();
  curSrc++;
 });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can try this demo in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2knz6sv/